# VSFTPD fails to start

Tags: 18.04, server, ftp, vsftpd

I have setup VSFTPD on a server with UBUNTU 18.04 on a server with both ipv4 and ipv6 support and the service is running as expected.

I have then ported the same configuration to a server with only ipv4 support and the service is exiting with error.

The configuration is:

```
listen=NO
listen=127.0.0.1
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to SmartRed FTP service.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
rsa_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.***.com/fullchain.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.***.com/privkey.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=41000
```

The service on restart gives the following feedback

> ● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-05-21 17:06:24 CEST;
>   2s ago   Process: 2281 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
>   (code=exited, status=2)   Process: 2280 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p
>   /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 2281
>   (code=exited, status=2)

while there is nothing in the log in /etc/log/vsftpd.log

What is wrong with this configuration? Can I enable a more verbose log to see what is wrong with the configuration?

Comment: You have two `listen=` params. Looking at mine I have a `listen` and a `listen_ipv6` and I think those params are just YES/NO. I think there is a listen_address param if you need that. From the restart feedback it looks like a config issue, but may or may not be that.

Comment: fixed the listen directive (you were right it's doubled) but the error persists. Any hint on how to debug the configuration (like for example with postfix and dovecot that are really verbose on their log)? I have no feedback on the error from vsftpd log

Comment: actually LISTEN=YES did the trick. LISTEN binds to IPV4 (no need to put 127.0.0.1 for that) while listen_ipv6 is to enable ipv6 support (not yet! available on my host datacenter)